# VS Code breaks randomly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I use vs code to write react native javascript (so JSX) and randomly, my vs code will break. What I mean by this is autocomplete/snippets will cease to work, [the colors of text will get weird](http://prntscr.com/ibkg72), and hitting ctrl-s to save will take about 2 seconds in between when I use the hotkey and when the dot next to the file changes, (I use watchman to live reload the simulator on changes, and the simulator will also wait those 2 seconds because it isn't saved).

I use the same settings between two devices: my macbook pro, and a hackintosh, and it will break on both of them. I try reloading the window, quitting vs code, even restarting the device won't predictably fix this issue.

When I toggle developer, it will usually have a bunch of repeats of the EPIPE error but I don't know what it means [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ibim30). I love vs code but the random breaking makes it really frustrating to use. [Here are my extensions](http://prntscr.com/ibinzw). SOS!!

Error message: ERR write EPIPE: Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:813:14)

Comment: Based on your screenshots, it looks like a problem with the vscode-flow-ide extension. Have you tried disabling it to see if that fixes it? (Pro-tip: it's preferable that you copy the text in your error messages etc. into the question. That way other people can search for that text and find your question)

Comment: I uninstalled flow, and I'm still getting all these errors: http://prntscr.com/ibkw2u